# ios beta distribution with Free account

Tags: ios, google-fabric, fabric-beta

I have integrated Fabric Crashlytics sdk with my ios application, using the Fabric mac desktop app.
I archive my application using the free apple developer account. I uploaded the application using Fabric desktop app.
Setup with my email.
open the email on my iPhone and setup the fabric Beta webhooks.
But whenever i keep trying to download and install my application.
it will ends with unable to download app dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you have a free Apple Developer account, you can only install the app directly on your device via Xcode. This is a restriction of the [membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/). You can test on your one device registered via Xcode and only when distributed from Xcode to your device directly.

You need an Apple Individual, Organization, or Enterprise account in order to distribute to devices.

Comment: Hi Mike, i'm able to deploy my application on my device directly through xCode. But when i tried and compile to an archive and upload to fabric. And attempt to download it from Fabric Beta, it keeps failing. 
Any ideas? I'm sure i have about 1GB of space on my phone and my application does not take more then 150 mbs.

Comment: Are you using an individual, organization or enterprise Apple account?

Comment: I'm using the individual free developer account.

Comment: In that case, due to Apple's restrictions on that account, you can't distribute through any service other then Xcode directly to your device. For anything more then that, you need an Apple Organization Account which is $99 a year.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: @MikeBonnell in your answer you stated that "you need an Apple Individual, Organization, or Enterprise account in order to distribute to devices". Then, in a comment, you say one needs an Organization Account. I am a sole proprietor of my business, so I'm entitled only to have a (paid) individual account. Will I be able to distribute Beta builds using such account?